# isset($_SESSION) Not Working on Remote Server

Tags: php

I have a login page where user enters his username ans password. If successful I redirect him to index.php where I start a session:

```
session_start();
```

from index.php he can navigate to a different page ("p1.php") and on top of "p1.php" I have this check:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    exit;
} 
?>
```

This works on my local server, but when I deploy this on remote server `!isset($_SESSION)` always returns true.

What could be happening here?

EDIT: I found on my hosting provider side a request to add this in php.ini:

```
session_save_path("your home directory path"/phpsessions);
```

And to create a phpsessions folder in my path.

I did but that didn't help.

I tried to do this as well:

in index.php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['lecturer_id']))
{
    echo "lecturer_id set";
    $_SESSION['lecturer_id'] = $_REQUEST['lecturer_id']; // store session data
}
```

and in p1.php:
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['lecturer_id'])) 
    { 
      exit;
    }

And the page always exits i.e. session variable is not defined

Comment: Do you have errors enabled?

Comment: Do you issue a session_start() in the p1.php page?

Comment: Is the `session_start();` on the top of every page or is it enclosed in an `if` statement?

Comment: no session_start is on top of index.php page

Comment: I don't see why this important question got a negative rating!
Whatever is the code, the guy tells you that it works on his local server. So, try to focus on the actual question: "Why does it not work on the remote server". I have the same question and my code is certainly OK (with session_start() at the top, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to make sure you have `session_start();` at the very top of your p1.php page and any page that uses session data.

Comment: Nope. From php manual - "session_start() creates a session or **resumes the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."

Comment: ok but when I do now session_start() in p1.php then I ask for "if(!isset($_SESSION['lecturer_id'])) exit;", this still exits

Comment: Note: the way I call p1.php from index.php is by loading p1.php page with no parameters. Is this OK?

Comment: @Kam I'm not sure I understand, but make sure you're properly setting your `$_SESSION['lecturer_id']` with a value such as a string or integer. Any page with `session_start()` can access that session variable. On every page that uses session data (or just every page to be safe), you'll need the basic 2 lines of `session_start()` followed by your `if (!isset($_SESSION['lecturer_id'])) exit;`.

Comment: ok in index.php I did this: session_start();$_SESSION['lecturer_id'] = 1;

Comment: and in p1.php I did this: session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION['lecturer_id']) exit; and I still exit

Comment: When you POST the username/password, I recommend passing them to a file that checks if they're valid (which I'm sure you're doing), set the session variable, then redirect to index.php. For instance, your form might pass the POST info to a process.php, which sets and checks everything, then redirect to index.php once all is set. I think you might already be doing this. Just making sure we're on the same page

Comment: I have a login.php where user enters his username and password. When I determine its successfull I post to index.php and I pass userid of the user. In index.php I take that userid and I put it in a session variable. but then as soon as I browse away to another page that variable is no longer valid...

Comment: ah. Make a new file between the login.php and the index.php to process the POST data. Something like process.php. Let index simply be a landing page **after** all the checks have been made. Process.php will pass the userid and put it in a session variable. Then redirect to index

Comment: I can't see the difference sorry :$ can you tell me why? BTW I do have a process.php file that checks the username and password but now it doesn't start a session nor save the session variable.

Comment: And Please note that this entire thing works locally, it just doesnt on the hosting server

Answer (score 1):

The server is most likely creating a PHP session silently which your local server is not configured to do.

Try checking for a specific `$_SESSION` eg `$_SESSION['x']` rather than just a `$_SESSION`.

Edit:
Instead of checking `isset($_SESSION)` you should check for whatever session variable you set specifically: `isset($_SESSION['SESSION_VARIABLE_YOU_SET'])`

`isset($_SESSION)` returns true once `session_start()` is called, that's why you need to check for the specific `$_SESSION` variable you set

Comment: if `$_SESSION['key']` is set then `isset($_SESSION)` will definitely return true. And the PHP session id is not stored anywhere in $_SESSION.

Comment: how can I find 'x'? should I contact my hosting providers?

Comment: Added a bit more detail to my answer

Comment: I added echo var_dump($_SESSION) right after session_start in index.php and it returned "array(0) { }"

Comment: Which will resolve to true if you call `isset()` on it. You need to check for a specific $_SESSION index.

Comment: in index.php I start session and I set  $_SESSION['lecturer_id'] = 10;

Comment: then in p1.php I check on top  "if(!isset($_SESSION['lecturer_id'])) exit;" that returns true and the page exits

Comment: I know this is crazy, but would isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the remote server is configured for session autostart. If you can configure this php instance you can check it in php.ini file (session_autostart directive).

Update: Sorry, I did not understand correctly your question. Really, if session autostart is set to "on" session always exists. You can not use isset($_SESSION) to determine if user is logged or not.

Comment: If it's autostarting wouldn't $_SESSION always be set?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same scenario and what I did was I unset the first the variable for example, `$_SESSION['loggedin']`),

I will unset it first using :

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
```

then i will comment out `unset($_SESSION['loggedin'])`;

the problem solved.